# How to start with the first axis tick at the origin in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2

I would like to always start with the first axis tick at the origin, such as in this image:

[image]

Playing around with `xlim`, `expand_limits` or `scale_x_continuous` doesn't really work - there's always a little spacing between first axis tick and origin. There should be an easy way to do this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the `breaks` argument in `scale_x_continuous`?

Comment: @RichardTelford Still gives padding of the first tick (not at origin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to set the option `expand=c(0,0)` together with the limits option, e.g.:

```
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(10,NA))
```

Y axis then starts at the origin with the first tick with label `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `ggplot2` is set up expand the axes and thus pad the axis ticks, and there's not a simple function to force them to be flush at the origin. I find the best way to get axis ticks at the origin is to use `coord_cartesian()` to turn off axis expansion and manually specify limits

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, #turn off axis expansion (padding)
                  xlim = c(1, 6), ylim = c(10, 35)) #manually set limits
```

I prefer to define limits in `coord_cartesian()` rather than in `scale_y_...()` and `scale_x_...()` because `coord_cartesian()` crops the view but does not alter the underlying data. `scale...()` functions remove data outside the limits, which could mess up fitted lines (`stat_smooth()`) or summary stats if you crop out an outlier.

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot. Interestingly, I can't use a wildcard (`NA`) for the upper limit with your solution. So for those who don't want to spend time determining the upper limit are better off with my solution.

Comment: Yes, `coord_cartesian()` and `scale_...()` behave a little bit differently with respect to limits, there are definitely some times it's better to use one and other times it's better to use the other.